# strcpy() implementation.. How to initialize a passing pointer to a function in the function itself

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcpy

I'm trying to implement strcpy() standard function, as a function taking two pointers to characters and returning nothing.

I've done the job right, but to avoid segmentation fault I had to initialize "dest" pointer in the main function before assigning it to the strcpy() function. I've tried to do this initialization in the strcpy() function itself but couldn't because I'm sending the pointer (the address of the characters) by value, so I can't change it in the function although I can change what the pointer points to not the point itself.

May be a solution to pass a pointer to pointer to the strcpy() function, but I want it to act like the standard function, taking pointers to character not a pointer to pointer.

Concisely, how can I avoid segmentation fault by initializing the pointer in the strcpy() function itself not in the main function?

I hope my question is clear

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void myStrcpy(char *dest,const char *src){

    while(*src)
    {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    *dest='\0';
}

int main(void){

    char *src="Salahuddin";
    int len=strlen(src);
    char *dest=(char*)malloc(len);


    myStrcpy(dest,src);


    printf("%s",dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to try to implement `strdup`, this is a different interface.

Comment: Also, `strcpy` has a different signature, it returns the `dest` string. This would a possibility to return a newly allocated `char[]`.

Comment: `...=(char*)malloc(len)` should be `...=malloc(len + 1)`.  i.e. don't cast return of (m/c)alloc(), and you need the extra byte for null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Indirection only goes one-way.  You cannot change the pointer unless you pass its address in or return a value to it.

Comment: @Salahuddin `strcpy()` expects to receive a pointer as `dest` to allocated memory that it can then write into with no further mallocing required.

Comment: @Salahuddin the standard strcpy() function works pretty much like yours (though it also returns the `dest` pointer). The standard strcpy() does not initialize the dest pointer, it might crash just as your own function if you have not initialized the dest pointer. (There's an error though, `(char*)malloc(len);` should be `(char*)malloc(len + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You cant without changing the signature of the API.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare your function as

```
void myStrcpy(char *&dest,const char *src)
                    ^   look here!
```

It will solve this problem

> May be a solution to pass a pointer to pointer to the strcpy()
>   function, but I want it to act like the standard function, taking
>   pointers to character not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: I don't know this syntax: `char *&dest`  what does it mean?

Comment: This is C++ and not C. You can do this : `void myStrcpy(char **dest, const char *src)`.

Answer (score -1):

Why couldn't you do this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void myStrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    if (dest == NULL) {
        dest = (char *) malloc(strlen(src));
    }

    while(*src) {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    *dest='\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char *src="Salahuddin";
    int len=strlen(src);
    char *dest=NULL;

    myStrcpy(dest, src);

    printf("%s", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

You could also use the `calloc` function instead of `malloc`, which automatically initializes the allocated memory to '\0'.

Of course, you have to be careful and make sure you free your memory in either scenario... but you should be able to allocate the memory in the function.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I tried to do so, but couldn't. You can't alter or change dest in myStrcpy(), and if you do, you'll just change a copy of it, not the pointer itself because it's passed by value. In other words,in myStrcpy, you can change what the pointer 'dest' points at, not the pointer itself

Comment: `printf("%s", dest);` uses the original value of `dest` or `NULL`, not the one assigned in `myStrcpy()`

Comment: You definitely would have to pass in an address then. It's been a little while, but I thought I remembered doing something like this in the past.

Comment: Also, strcpy returns a pointer, not void. It's defined as: 

char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);

Answer (score -1):

***Responding to this only:*** *I'm trying to implement strcpy() standard function, as a function taking two pointers to characters and returning nothing.*

If that first sentence is an accurate representation of what you *really want*,
***Then write a wrapper*** around `strcpy()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *dest;
    char src[] = {"some string");
    dest = calloc(sizeof(src), sizeof(char));
    myStrcpy(dest, src);
    //use dest
    free(dest);
    return 0;
}

void myStrcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    strcpy(dest, src);
}
```

This is bare bones, but with some error checking, it will do what you described in your intro sentence.

Comment: Man, are you kidding me, in this code I'm trying to write my own strcpy() function

Comment: No, I am not kidding.  Its only a suggestion based on your ***first, and most prominent*** phrase (it has the arguments, and it returns nothing).  Wrappers around standard lib functions are done often and often for good reason.  If you cannot use it, then don't.  Also, I suggest you edit your answer to be less ambiguous about such things.

Comment: I think the title of the question is strcpy implementation, it's OK any way

Comment: Hmmm, First you say: ...implement strcpy() _standard_ function... then go on to describe a _non-standard_ implementation.  As written, you have little chance of any two people agreeing to what you are _really_ after, as is evidenced by the variation of offered answers.  My suggestion to edit the question was intended only to help you narrow the scope of what you are after so people answering can give you something you can use.  Your choice.